# Using SELECT * or SELECT all, cols is better for Queries

Tags: php, sql

If i have a database its columns like that

```
[id  -  col1  -  col2  -  col3]
```

If i wanted to retrieve all the data to use it ALL, Is it better to use

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM table
```

And if there is a difference, Why so?

And in case i'm not going to use the `id col` is it still better to use

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Comment: The main difference would be a smaller payload if you didn't need everything, but since you said you wanted all then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Augwa in which case it would be a smaller payload? And i updated the question.

Comment: The 'payload' is the amount of data the database needs to send back. So, if you don't select all columns the payload is smaller.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but isn't it the same if i just typed all the columns to be `SELECT`ed?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion that would be virtually the same. If you want to know: TEST IT. The best way to learn is to practice. So don't ask question and forget the answers, but try and fail, then try again. If you have tested things yourself you'll remember them much better.